# How do I ignore '.' in preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys I am trying to ignore periods using preg_match, so:

```
$pos1 = preg_match( "/.*(#\S+)/", $currentStatus , $match );
$hash = $match[1];
```

This will grab the 2 hashtag in twitter API but lets say they have #hi. <- it will grab the . to, so if someone puts a . by accident I want it to ignore that.

Not sure how to do this and would appreciate the help!

David

Comment: at this case you need to define a white list for example: a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: Ya sorry was not paying attention...@Nelson solved it, I appreciate it though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just remove the dot from the result:

```
$hash = str_replace('.','', $match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(#\S+[^\.\s])/', $currentStatus, $match);
```

or

```
preg_match('/(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $currentStatus, $match);
```